# How to create Table Of Contents in pdf file using iTextSharp with C#

Tags: c#, itext

I have found many Java examples, but I want C# examples any one to help me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Define table of contents. Are you talking about *outlines*? That's the table of contents that is shown in the left panel next to your page. Or are you talking about an index that is part of your document (e.g. the first or last set of pages). If the latter, us the purpose to print (not interactive) or do you want interactive links. You admit that you have found many Java examples, but there is no proof that you have tried to convert those examples to C#. All of this makes your question off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks i am able to do this please find below

Comment: Great! And thank you for posting the solution. That's useful for other people too.

Answer (score 2):

This the example i did

```
private void GeneratePdf()
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("APP_Data");
    Document doc = new Document();
    try
    {
        Guid newGd= Guid.NewGuid();
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(path + "/Anchors"+ newGd+".pdf", FileMode.Create));
        doc.Open();
        iTextSharp.text.Font link = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE);
        Anchor anchor = new Anchor("www.mikesdotnetting.com", link);
        anchor.Reference = "http://www.mikesdotnetting.com";

        Anchor click = new Anchor("Click to go to Target");
        click.Reference = "#target";
        Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
        p1.Add(click);
        doc.Add(p1);

        Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph();
        p2.Add(new Chunk("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"));
        doc.Add(p2);

        Anchor target = new Anchor("This is the Target");
        target.Name = "target";
        Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph();
        p3.Add(target);
        doc.Add(p3);
        Paragraph p4 = new Paragraph();
        p4.Add(new Chunk("Click "));
        p4.Add(new Chunk("here", link).SetLocalGoto("GOTO"));
        p4.Add(new Chunk(" to find local goto"));
        p4.Add(new Chunk("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"));

        Paragraph p5 = new Paragraph();
        p5.Add(new Chunk("Local Goto Destination").SetLocalDestination("GOTO"));

        doc.Add(p4);
        doc.Add(p5);
        Chapter chapter1 = new Chapter(new Paragraph("This is Chapter 1"), 1);
        Section section1 = chapter1.AddSection(20f, "Section 1.1", 2);
        Section section2 = chapter1.AddSection(20f, "Section 1.2", 2);
        Section subsection1 = section2.AddSection(20f, "Subsection 1.2.1", 3);
        Section subsection2 = section2.AddSection(20f, "Subsection 1.2.2", 3);
        Section subsubsection = subsection2.AddSection(20f, "Sub Subsection 1.2.2.1", 4);
        Chapter chapter2 = new Chapter(new Paragraph("This is Chapter 2"), 1);
        Section section3 = chapter2.AddSection("Section 2.1", 2);
        Section subsection3 = section3.AddSection("Subsection 2.1.1", 3);
        Section section4 = chapter2.AddSection("Section 2.2", 2);
        chapter1.BookmarkTitle = "Changed Title";
        chapter1.BookmarkOpen = true;
        chapter2.BookmarkOpen = false;
        doc.Add(chapter1);
        doc.Add(chapter2);
        doc.Add(anchor);
    }
    catch (DocumentException dex)
    {
        Response.Write(dex.Message);
    }
    catch (IOException ioex)
    {
        Response.Write(ioex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        doc.Close();
    }
}
```